# Usage of @Injectable class decorator on service provided by @Global module (in official documentation)

Tags: nestjs, code-documentation

Questions about a **ConfigService** **in documentation**:
[https://**docs**.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#service](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#service)

See the class definition there:

```
export class ConfigService { /* ... */ }
```

Why there is no **@Injectable** decorator? Is there any reason or just a mistake? Has **@Injectable** decorator any impact on a fact the module that provides `ConfigService` might be **@Global**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no @Injectable decorator because this class is used as a custom provider. See follow the usage:

```
{
  provide: ConfigService,
  useValue: new ConfigService(`${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`),
},
```

In that case, your able to specify the token and the value that you want to use, here the configService is instantiate manually and not by the DI system.

When you use the @Injectable decorator you tell to nestjs that this class as to be instantiate by the framework.

I hope this will help you to understand.

Comment: So, here we instantiate the service class already in a module, therefore "Injectable" decorator is not applied. I've ended up in those articles too:

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers

and

https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#custom-providers

Thanx @adrien-de-peretti, that was helpful.

Comment: My pleasure, if the answer help you can you mark it as resolved to be seen by anybody else if they have the same question. Thank you

Comment: You should be able to put the answer as valid